# *ngFor not working properly with bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to create multiple dropdown buttons that contain links to popups. This is my HTML code:

```
<div *ngFor="let service of index.value | keyvalue: unsorted; let j = index" class ="btn-group">
      <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li *ngFor ="let key of service.value | keyvalue: unsorted">   
          <ng-template #tipContent>Timestamp: {{key.value}} </ng-template>
          <button *ngIf="key.key.includes('timestamp')" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent" id = "msg{{i}}{{j}}" [style.marginLeft.px] = "getLeftMargin(j)">
            {{service.key}}
          </button>


<!-- Error occurs here, unable to create this menu --> 
          <div *ngFor ="let msg of key.value | keyvalue: unsorted" class="dropdown-menu">
            <ng-template #tipContent>Timestamp: {{msg.value}} </ng-template>

          <!-- When this button is clicked, it displays a popup with the message in the div below -->
          <button *ngIf ="msg.key.includes('InTimestamp')" class ="dropdown-item" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent"  (click)="openPopUp(trace.traceId+'Incoming'+service.key)">
            Incoming
          </button>  
            <div *ngIf ="msg.key.includes('Incoming')" id="msg{{trace.traceId}}Incoming{{service.key}}" class ="modal">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <span id="close{{trace.traceId}}Incoming{{service.key}}" class='close'>&times;</span>
              <p>{{msg.value}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          
          
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
          </div>
         
      
 
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
```

Whenever I click the drop down menu I get this error:

> zone-evergreen.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'setAttribute' of null

Why do I keep getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: where is your code where you reference setAttribute?

Comment: @rhavelka I don't have any code where I reference setAttribute. It's an error I get from bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The following line

`<div *ngFor ="let msg of key.value | keyvalue: unsorted" class="dropdown-menu">`

would create multiple `div` tags with `class="dropdown-menu"`

I am not an expert of html but that does not seem right. From a quick search here is how someone would use it

```
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
         <a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor ="let msg of key.value | keyvalue: unsorted" href="#">{{msg}}</a>           
      </div>
```

Comment: I tested it out by removing the class and it works as expected. I don't think the key is empty.

Comment: what have you removed?

Comment: I removed this class from the div: "dropdown-menu".
unsorted is just an empty function that I use to sort the messages as they were entered in the object: unsorted() { }

Comment: I didn't say anything about the class there. Either the pipe or the values have a problem, that's what I meant

Comment: I have checked it with and without the pipe, the error still persists. I checked in console and it seems that there is an issue with the value which is confusing. When I run the code without the class "dropdown-menu", the values appear as expected. Not sure what's happening.